# Values sent via React JS/Axios are removed when received by the PHP backend

Tags: php, reactjs, json, axios

I have the  JSON value in React JS called formdata

```
{
    account_id: account_id? account_id : "null",
    name: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    is_active: true,
    filters:{
      minBlockRate: 20,
      minRatePerHour: 10,
      hours: {
        startTime: "00:00",
        endTime: "23:55",
      },
      weekdays: {
        Monday: true,
        Tuesday: true,
        Wednesday: true,
        Thursday: true,
        Friday: true,
        Saturday: true,
        Sunday: true
      },
      warehouses: [],
    },
    timezone: "America/New_York",
  }
```

This is sended through Axios

```
axios.post(ProjectConfig.api_url, null,
      {
        headers:{
          'LTKN': cookies.get('ltkn'),
        },
        params: {
          request: 'login',
          formdata: formValues
        }
      })
        .then((response) => {
.... REST OF CODE
```

When the PHP API receive this, the key/value Warehouses are deleted.

here is the way how the value is received.

```
case 'login':
$formdata = $_REQUEST['formdata'];
$manual_token = $_REQUEST['manual_token'];
```

If I do a json_encode to $formdata, the result is

`{ "account_id":"null", "name":"Juan", "email":"ambarmalave@yahoo.com", "password":"123", "is_active":"true", "filters":{ "minBlockRate":"20", "minRatePerHour":"10", "hours":{ "startTime":"00:00", "endTime":"23:55" }, "weekdays":{ "Monday":"true", "Tuesday":"true", "Wednesday":"true", "Thursday":"true", "Friday":"true", "Saturday":"true", "Sunday":"true" } }, "timezone":"America\/New_York" }`

I don´t know where is the issue here. React or PHP

Aditional info.

- React js / axios, send the JSON object like JSON, so, I don´t need to use json_decode to format it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surely the json object should be POSTed and received as the body, not as a parameter.

```
axios.post(ProjectConfig.api_url, formValues,
      {
        headers:{
          'LTKN': cookies.get('ltkn'),
        },
        params: {
          request: 'login'
        }
      })
```

And receive with PHP as follows:

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
```

Comment: In this case works perfectly, but, how I could implement this using get? I try, sending as data: "mydata" but the php "file_get_contents('php://input')" not caught it.

Comment: With a GET request you do not have a body so you need to send the fields as parameters - https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-make-an-axios-get-request#. On the PHP server side read the params like this - https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_superglobals_get.asp